# how to increase max memory usage in build.sbt

Tags: scala, sbt, sbt-native-packager

I have a

```
build.sbt
```

file that looks something like this

```
lazy val `tokens-service` = (project in file("modules/some-service"))
  .configure(commonSettings)
  .enablePlugins(...)
  .settings(
    publishArtifact  := false,
    name             := "example",
    buildInfoPackage := "com.some.path",
    javaAgents ++= d.JavaAgents,
    libraryDependencies ++= List.concat(
    ),
  )
  .dependsOn(
    deps(`something`)
  )
```

I want to set the max heap memory to 4352M, I tried adding this line to my module settings

```
scalacOptions += "-JXmx4352M"
```

and also

```
javaOptions += "-JXmx4352M"
```

Then I run

```
sbt example/Universal/stage
```

However, when I check the shell script produced by sbt which I think should be in this path

```
modules/example/target/universal/scripts/bin/example
```

I don't see the max heap being set anywhere. I was expecting to see the new parameter JXmx4352M being passed in. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong? Maybe I'm looking in the wrong scripts and it is working? I would like to know how to verify this new parameter is being passed in the script produced by sbt and would appreciate any help

Comment: I ended up passing Universal / javaOptions += "-J-Xmx4352Mi" and was able to confirm it's being passed in
modules/example/target/universal/tmp/conf/application.ini

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to scope your javaOptions like `Universal / javaOptions += ...`

Comment: And how would I confirm that it's working? Do you know where in the produced script it would be after I run sbt example/Universal/stage?

Comment: You can check `conf/application.ini` in you stage directory or alternatively add `-XX:+PrintFlagsFinal` to your java options and check output at application startup.

Comment: I cannot find conf/application.ini, I run sbt example/Universal/stage but doesn't seem to produce this file

Comment: I found application.ini, the path looked something like this modules/example/target/universal/tmp/conf/application.ini

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can set this option in `.jvmopts` file this way:

```
-Xms1G
-Xmx4G
```

Comment: Thanks, will do this if I can't figure out how to do it in build.sbt but would rather do it there since it's easier to manage and I can apply it to specific modules only